# Using ARCore and Vision SDK together Android

Tags: android, arcore, google-vision, text-recognition, android-augmented-reality

Working on an idea of detecting the text using the google vision sdk and then placing the corresponding ar node on the screen. This detection and placing ar node has to be on same activity and not two different activities. Is it possible to combine both (arcore and Vision) on same activity.

Comment: Hello did you find answer for this question ? I am facing the same